# Optaplanner: Own isdoable Method for given MoveSelectors

Tags: optaplanner

my task is to create a processing sequence of furniture. Within the furniture to be produced, individual pieces of furniture can occur several times. If OptaPlanner exchanges two pieces of furniture in the schedule that are identical to each other, this does not change the Makespan to be minimized. Therefore I wanted to write my own isdoable method that prevents such moves. But in the documentation I don't find how to proceed here. I have already adapted the eqauls and hash method to recognize two pieces of furniture that are identical. Nevertheless, OptaPlanner performs such moves.
Maybe one of you knows how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documentation for implementing `isMoveDoable`, this should do what you need.

https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.41.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#theInterfaceMove

Since you are not implementing custom moves you can use the [Entity Selection Filter](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.40.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#filteredEntitySelection) for existing OptaPlanner Moves.

If you are using tabu search you can specify an [Entity Tabu](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.40.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#tabuSearchConfiguration) to avoid modifying the same entity in consecutive moves.

Based on your other comments I think the Selection Filter is the better approach though.

Comment: dont I have to implement my own move to use the interface? However, I would like to add another condition for the already implemented moves (changeMoveSelector, SwapMoveSelector) that must be checked before the move can be taken

Comment: I assumed you already had a custom move, updated the answer to be more inline with what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for ur help. It worked as assumed with the Entity Selection Filter.

Answer (score 1):

Before implementing custom moves, I would recommend finding out which kind of move produces such an unwanted result. See [logging configuration](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#logging) to switch the logging level to "trace" to make the OptaPlanner print information about each move.

Both `ChangeMove` and `SwapMove` already allow only moves that change (or swap) different values.

Comment: Does this mean that Optaplanner only compares the values and not the entitites? The values always vary, but the two entities that are swapped are identical, so they should not be swapped. Optaplanner should give different values to the entities so that they get to a different place in the schedule, like for example in the schedule abbca, Optaplanner should not put b in front of the other b and should not swap the two a's, as this would not change the result. At the moment, Optaplanner performs both of these unwanted moves.